# Inconsistent reputation history for days without reputation changes

Tags: bug, reputation, user-profiles

My recent SU reputation history:

[image: Screenshot]

- *There is an entry* for Jan 3, on which *There were no net reputation changes on this day*. No posts are listed for this day.
- *There is no entry* for Dec 29.

It is unclear why Jan 3 gets its own (empty) entry, while Dec 29 doesn't. IIRC there was a quickly reverted up vote on Jan 3 (not sure about the date, but it'd make sense in this context). It could have been easy to forget about this rep change or even miss it completely.

**There is absolutely no (non-technical) reason to distinguish this way between "no votes" days and "reverted votes" days in the reputation history.** Either make sure that all days get their entries, or that days without data are removed from the list.